# Problem with xml

Tags: xml, dtd, cdata, pcdata

I am  novice to xml...I just started studying xml....I have the following doubts..
The following is my xml code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<!DOCTYPE book [
<!ELEMENT book (page)>
<!ELEMENT page (heading,#PCDATA)>

 ]>
<note>
<page>
    hhh<heading>c</heading><heading>s</heading>
</page>
</note>
```

When i opened this in browser ,it shown that there is an error with #PCDATA...when i replaced it with PCDATA it showed no error...According to my DTD, page can contain exactly one heading element...am i right?But when i opened it in browser it showed no error even if i have two heading elements..Why did it happen..Also what is the difference between CDATA and PCDATA....

Answer (score 4):

Use this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<!DOCTYPE note [
  <!ELEMENT note (page)>
  <!ELEMENT page (#PCDATA|heading)*>
  <!ELEMENT heading (#PCDATA)>

]>
<note>
  <page>
    hhh<heading>c</heading><heading>s</heading>
  </page>
</note>
```

> **PCDATA** is text that WILL be parsed by a parser. The text will be
> examined by the parser for entities and markup.
>
> **CDATA** is text that will NOT be parsed by a parser. Tags inside the
> text will NOT be treated as markup and entities will not be expanded.

Answer (score 4):

My advice is to pick up some solid validating parser, for example [AltovaXML](http://www.altova.com/altovaxml.html) (Community Edition) is very straightforward to use:

```
altovaxml -validate document.xml
```

Let's look what's wrong with your DTD. First of all your document element (root) is not named `book`, so we got first error from here:

> Error in referenced Schema or DTD. Element  does not match root
>   element name 'book' from the DTD.

Second thing is that `heading` is not declared:

> Element  has not been declared.

Finally to allow [mixed content](http://www.w3.org/TR/2008/REC-xml-20081126/#sec-mixed-content) put choice with `#PCDATA` (that means parsed character data) **at first** and `heading` element:

Finally your DTD is:

```
<!DOCTYPE note [
    <!ELEMENT note (page)>
    <!ELEMENT page (#PCDATA | heading)*>
    <!ELEMENT heading (#PCDATA)>
]>
```

Comment: <!DOCTYPE book [
   <!ELEMENT book (page)>
   <!ELEMENT page (heading|#PCDATA)>
   <!ELEMENT heading (#PCDATA)>
   ]>
Why book is not my root element....also ..if 
    <!ELEMENT note(page,heading)>
is correct why <!ELEMENT page(#PCDATA,heading)> is incorrect

 ]>

Comment: @user822982: Good question, `<!ELEMENT page(#PCDATA,heading)>` is  incorrect in DTD, because you can't put `#PCDATA` in **sequence** element content. I think [that thread](http://lists.xml.org/archives/xml-dev/199911/msg00583.html) and its answers should be helpful for you.